How do I *force* remove a package?
I've been trying to delete git-commit since it is now distributed as a part of Magit.
I've checked this answer and the package menu guide, but I can't seem to find a way to force uninstall a package. Using M-x package-delete and the package menu both yield the following error:
Error trying to delete ‘git-commit-20240831.2335’: (error "Package ‘git-commit-20240831.2335’ is used by ‘magit’ as dependency, not deleting")

...I was wondering if there was a sane and reasonable way to accomplish this without manually deleting the package directories.


I've been trying to delete git-commit since it is now distributed as a part of Magit.

...

Error trying to delete ‘git-commit-20240831.2335’: (error "Package ‘git-commit-20240831.2335’ is used by ‘magit’ as dependency, not deleting")

Obviously the version of Magit you have installed has a dependency on git-commit
You could delete your current magit, then delete git-commit, then install the latest magit.
I also see nothing particularly wrong with deleting the files from your config directly.

Have you already tried supplying a prefix argument?  (Seems like this has been supported since Emacs 25.)
package-delete is an interactive native-compiled Lisp function in
`package.el'.

(package-delete PKG-DESC &optional FORCE NOSAVE)

Delete package PKG-DESC.

Argument PKG-DESC is a full description of package as vector.
Interactively, prompt the user for the package name and version.

When package is used elsewhere as dependency of another package,
refuse deleting it and return an error.
If prefix argument FORCE is non-nil, package will be deleted even
if it is used elsewhere.
If NOSAVE is non-nil, the package is not removed from
`package-selected-packages'.


I did try this, but then magit was also a tree sitter dependency.

Well that sounds bananas.  Why on earth does tree sitter care about a Git client?

I've added a possible solution to the answer.  Not sure if you've already tried it.

Ooh, yes, the force prefix is exactly what I was looking for, thank-you so much.
